# UpsertDE to 1 column DE not working

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions

I'm trying to Upsert records during an email send to a 1-column de. I've tried a couple different variants but in all cases, the Email Send time out and never occurs. If I remove the Upsert the email goes out without any issue.

The column in EmailAddress, which is type EmailAdress and is a primary key.

Here are the different variations I've tried:

```
SET @result = UpsertDE("TestDE", 1, "EmailAddress", EmailAddress, "EmailAddress", EmailAddress)

SET @result = UpsertDE("TestDE", 1, "EmailAddress", EmailAddress)

SET @result = UpsertDE("TestDE", 0, "EmailAddress", EmailAddress)
```

In all three cases, the email builds when I preview it, but will never send. It always ends up 'Canceled'. I've tried doing both test sends and actual sends using DE. If anyone knows if there is an issue with trying to upsert to a  1 column DE?

Comment: If my answer helped, please mark it as accepted, so others can easily identify this has been solved. Thank you!

Comment: What's the business case for needing to do an UpsertDE in an email?

Comment: MarkusSlabina yes, this works. I don't know why we didn't think of this solution. I marked your answer down below.

 @AdamSpriggs The DE contains a list of emails that are active members of a group. We use it in a number of automatons but currently the list was being updated once a month (as we need to pull this data from an outside source.) We finally moved the confirmation email for this group into MC and it gets triggered by one of our other systems. So now we are adding people to this list when we send them the confirmation to have the data updated more quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what the exact problem is here. However, upserting a row - which is updating it if present or inserting it if not - doesn't make sense with a single-column data extension as there is no way of updating a row if the only identifier should itself be updated as the values are identical. Therefore that could be the problem.

If you are just trying to insert a record with the email address if it isn't present yet, then you could use the following AMPscript code:

```
%%[
 SET @lookup = LookUpRows("TestDE", "EmailAddress", AttributeValue("EmailAddress"))
 IF RowCount(@lookup) < 1 THEN
    SET @result = InsertDE("TestDE", "EmailAddress", AttributeValue("EmailAddress"))
 ENDIF
]%%
```